# What's so funny about starched collars?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, bobby-deerfield

In *Bobby Deerfield*, Bobby said this to Karl whose neck is injured and wearing a collar,

> You have to tell them, Karl, no more starch in the collars.

Why are they laughing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you send your shirt to be cleaned, you can ask them to [starch your collar](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-laundry-starch.htm) to keep it from curling. So Bobby is just humorously saying that the [cervical collar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervical_collar) is the result of the launderers over-starching Karl's shirt collar rather than his injury.

Comment: Cervical......?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervical_collar): A cervical collar, also known as a neck brace, is a medical device used to support a person's neck. It is also used by emergency personnel for those who have had traumatic head or neck injuries, and can be used to treat chronic medical conditions.